# String interpolation in Chainlink TOML jobspecs

Tags: chainlink

I've got a HTTP POST task that's sending a lump of JSON to the GraphQL External Adapter.

When I send a literal regular JSON string it works fine.

`{\\"jobRunId\\":1,\\"data\\":{\\"query\\":\\"query rightToLeft ($code: ID!) {language(code: $code) { rtl }}\\",\\"variables\\":{\\"code\\":\\"ar\\"},\\"graphqlEndpoint\\":\\"https://countries.trevorblades.com/\\"}}`

When I replace `{\\"code\\":\\"ar\\"}` with `{\\"code\\":\\"$(decode_cbor.languageCode)\\"}` I get the following error when the HTTP POST task is executed

```
requestData: while unmarshalling JSON: invalid character '_' after object key:value pair; js: {"jobRunId":1,"data":{"query":"query rightToLeft ($code: ID!) {language(code: $code) { rtl }}","variables":{"code":"{ "__chainlink_key_path__": "decode_cbor.languageCode" }"},"graphqlEndpoint":"https://countries.trevorblades.com/"}}: bad input for task
```

I'm trying to use the `$(foo)` notation that's documented here https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/task-types/http/

Here's the complete jobspec's observationSource:

```
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    post         [type="http" method=POST url="https://ea-graphql-k3zq5wb52q-uc.a.run.app/" requestData="{\\"jobRunId\\":1,\\"data\\":{\\"query\\":\\"query rightToLeft ($code: ID!) {language(code: $code) { rtl }}\\",\\"variables\\":{\\"code\\":\\"$(decode_cbor.languageCode)\\"},\\"graphqlEndpoint\\":\\"https://countries.trevorblades.com/\\"}}"]

    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="result,data,language,rtl" data="$(post)"]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bool value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\":   $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                  ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x188b71C9d27cDeE01B9b0dfF5C1aff62E8D6F434" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> post -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ijonas, your observation source looks correct, I am wondering if you failed to add the `languageCode` as a query param in your ChainlinkClient in the smart contract or if the CBOR payload is parsed.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for replying to my post. The `decode_cbor` task in the previous step in the pipeline returns `{"languageCode":"ar"}` so I don't think that's the problem.